# I can't install a custom recovery

Tags: custom-roms

I'm trying to install a custom recovery on my phone. My phone model name is LYF LS 5014(LYF Wind 4). But I can't find the model name of my phone in any website to download the custom recovery. What should I do now.....

Answer (score 0):

Ethan Yonkers (Dees Troy) the Developer of TWRP has your answer, build it yourself, as long as the manufacturer follows the GPL license guidelines and releases the kernel source it isn't super difficult... https://plus.google.com/+DeesTroy/posts/iyyM1kYULEa

> Requesting TWRP for unsupported devices
>
> There seems to be a lot of misunderstanding about what devices we
>   support and why we choose to support certain devices over others.
>   Official support for a device usually comes about in one of two ways:
>   1) We somehow get our hands on the device either through someone or a
>   company donating the device to us or occasionally we save up enough
>   money to purchase a device ourselves. 2) Another developer who
>   actually owns the device steps up and ports TWRP to their device, then
>   they work with us to get their device added to our official
>   distribution.
>
> Occasionally there's a third method where we work with a remote tester
>   who owns the device to get the device working in TWRP. This third
>   method is not used very often because by and large, remote testers are
>   epic failures. Remote testers often need tons of hand holding and
>   line-by-line directions. Remote testers often fail to know how to get
>   things like adb and fastboot working. Remote testers often fail to
>   make themselves available when we need them and they disappear before
>   we're able to finish verifying a completely working build. At this
>   point, we usually only work with remote testers that we already know
>   and have a relationship with so that we can ensure that we're not
>   wasting our valuable time working with someone who doens't know what
>   they're doing and will disappear before the job is done.
>
> Sure, you can offer files and to be a tester and offer to provide
>   everything we need, but most likely you'll be ignored because we
>   simply don't have the time.
>
> You can compile TWRP yourself by following this guide:
>   http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1943625 To put it
>   short, you will need:
>   -A Linux environment, either virtual or native
>   -A full Omni build tree, about a 15 or 20GB download
>   -A copy of the stock recovery and/or kernel source for your device
>   -A basic knowledge of adb, fastboot, Linux command line, make files, and strong ability to figure things out on your own via searching on
>   Google
>
> If none of the above works for you, feel free to donate the cash or
>   ship us your device and we'll try to work on it when we get a chance.

Remember that to use custom recovery, your bootloader must be unlocked.